# How to 'bulk update' with Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to update a table with Django - something like this in raw SQL:

```
update tbl_name set name = 'foo' where name = 'bar'
```

My first result is something like this - but that's nasty, isn't it?

```
list = ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar')
for obj in list:
    obj.name = 'foo'
    obj.save()
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You might be looking for batch insert. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294088/accelerate-bulk-insert-using-djangos-orm

Comment: I don't like to insert new data - just update existing.

Comment: Maybe with help of select_for_update? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update

Comment: What is not nasty about the `ModelClass` approach? Then feed to Django as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/executing-python-script-from-django-shell

Answer (score 362, accepted):

### Update:

Django 2.2 version now has a [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update).

### Old answer:

Refer to the following django documentation section

> [Updating multiple objects at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

In short you should be able to use:

```
ModelClass.objects.filter(name='bar').update(name="foo")
```

You can also use `F` objects to do things like incrementing rows:

```
from django.db.models import F
Entry.objects.all().update(n_pingbacks=F('n_pingbacks') + 1)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/).

However, note that:

- This won't use `ModelClass.save` method (so if you have some logic inside it won't be triggered).
- No django signals will be emitted.
- You can't perform an `.update()` on a sliced QuerySet, it must be on an original QuerySet so you'll need to lean on the `.filter()` and `.exclude()` methods.

Comment: Note also that as a consequence of not using `save()`, `DateTimeField` fields with `auto_now=True` ("modified" columns) won't be updated.

Comment: But `ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar').update(name="foo")` does not fulfill purpose of bulk update, if i have different data for different ids the how could i do that without using loop ?

Comment: @shihon I'm not sure if I got you right but I added example to the answer.

Comment: @Shashank have you found any solution for your case yet ? I am also having the same scenario .

Comment: F objects cannot be used to reference different models in the .update method... for example you can't use `Entry.objects.all().update(title=F('blog__title'))`. Docs have a small mention of this.
If you want to pull data from another model to update your entries, you'll have to run a for loop

Comment: Don't forget to use the `batch_size` parameter of `bulk_update`

Answer (score 34):

Django 2.2 version now has a `bulk_update` method ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#models)).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

Example:

```
# get a pk: record dictionary of existing records
updates = YourModel.objects.filter(...).in_bulk()
....
# do something with the updates dict
....
if hasattr(YourModel.objects, 'bulk_update') and updates:
    # Use the new method
    YourModel.objects.bulk_update(updates.values(), [list the fields to update], batch_size=100)
else:
    # The old & slow way
    with transaction.atomic():
        for obj in updates.values():
            obj.save(update_fields=[list the fields to update])
```

Comment: Indeed, [it is listed in the release notes for 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.2/#models)

Answer (score 33):

Consider using `django-bulk-update` found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update).

Install: `pip install django-bulk-update`

Implement: (code taken directly from projects ReadMe file)

```
from bulk_update.helper import bulk_update

random_names = ['Walter', 'The Dude', 'Donny', 'Jesus']
people = Person.objects.all()

for person in people:
    r = random.randrange(4)
    person.name = random_names[r]

bulk_update(people)  # updates all columns using the default db
```

**Update:** As Marc points out in the comments this is not suitable for updating thousands of rows at once. Though it is suitable for smaller batches 10's to 100's. The size of the batch that is right for you depends on your CPU and query complexity. This tool is more like a wheel barrow than a dump truck.

Comment: I tried django-bulk-update, and I personally discourage using it. What it does internally is to create a single SQL statement which looks like this: UPDATE "table" SET "field" = CASE "id" WHEN %s THEN %s WHEN %s THEN %s [...] WHERE id in (%s, %s, [...]);. This is kind of all right for few rows (when bulk updater is not needed), but with 10,000, the query is so complex, that postgres spends more time with CPU at 100% understanding the query, than the time it saves writing to disk.

Comment: @MarcGarcia good point. I found many developers use external libraries without knowing their impact

Comment: @MarcGarcia I disagree that bulk update is not valuable and only really needed when thousands of updates are necessary.  Using it to do 10,000 rows at once is not advisable for the reasons you mentioned, but using it to update 50 rows at once is much more efficient than hitting the db with 50 separate update requests.

Comment: @MarcGarcia Isn't this the only way to update it? there has to be a where clause. how could that be avoided?

Comment: The only way to update all rows at once is indeed with CASE and WHERE. But the problem is that the SQL becomes so complex, that it takes longer for the DB to understand it, than what it takes to insert the rows 1 by 1.

Comment: The best solutions I found are: a) use @transaction.atomic decorator, which improves performance by using a single transaction, or b) make a bulk insert in a temporary table, and then an UPDATE from the temporary table to the original one.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but actually CASE/WHERE is not the only way. For PostgreSQL there are other approaches, but they are DB specific e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799497
However I am not sure if this is possible in ANSI SQL

Comment: We are using this library batchwise (we use batches of size 1000). It speeds up the bulk updates of values considerably. However, as of yet it doesn't support upserts well ([one pullrequest](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update/pull/66) exists but is supposedly [not sql-injection save](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update/issues/69)). Therefore we are looking into [django-postgres-extra](https://github.com/SectorLabs/django-postgres-extra) which does do this (but as the name suggests is limited to Postgres, which is fine for us).

Comment: @MarcGarcia, would you provide examples of the two solutions you suggested?

Answer (score 19):

Here is a useful content which i found in internet regarding the above question

https://www.sankalpjonna.com/learn-django/running-a-bulk-update-with-django

**The inefficient way**

```
model_qs= ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar')
for obj in model_qs:
    obj.name = 'foo'
    obj.save()
```

**The efficient way**

```
ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar').update(name="foo") # for single value 'foo' or add loop
```

**Using bulk_update**

```
update_list = []
model_qs= ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar')
for model_obj in model_qs:
    model_obj.name = "foo" # Or what ever the value is for simplicty im providing foo only
    update_list.append(model_obj)
    
ModelClass.objects.bulk_update(update_list,['name'])
```

**Using an atomic transaction**

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    model_qs = ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar')
    for obj in model_qs:
       ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar').update(name="foo")
```

Any Up Votes ? Thanks in advance : Thank you for keep an attention ;)

Comment: Your bulk_update example makes no sense to me - why are you re-pulling the model_obj from the database? Same with the article you refer to - its bulk_update example doesnt need any db select at all, it just can do `User.objects.bulk_update([User(id=k, score=v) for k, v in user_ids_dict.items()], ['score'])`...

Answer (score 15):

If you want to **set the same value on a collection of rows**, you can use the update() method combined with any query term to update all rows in one query:

```
some_list = ModelClass.objects.filter(some condition).values('id')
ModelClass.objects.filter(pk__in=some_list).update(foo=bar)
```

If you want to **update a collection of rows with different values** depending on some condition, you can in best case batch the updates according to values. Let's say you have 1000 rows where you want to set a column to one of X values, then you could prepare the batches beforehand and then only run X update-queries (each essentially having the form of the first example above) + the initial SELECT-query.

If **every row requires a unique value** there is no way to avoid one query per update. Perhaps look into other architectures like CQRS/Event sourcing if you need performance in this latter case.

Answer (score 13):

To update with same value we can simply use this

```
ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar').update(name='foo')
```

To update with different values

```
ob_list = ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar')
obj_to_be_update = []
for obj in obj_list:
    obj.name = "Dear "+obj.name
    obj_to_be_update.append(obj)
ModelClass.objects.bulk_update(obj_to_be_update, ['name'], batch_size=1000)
```

It won't trigger save signal every time instead we keep all the objects to be updated on the list and trigger update signal at once.

Comment: Your second case should still work with update, something like that: `ModelClass.objects.filter(name='bar').update(name = 'Dear ' + F('name'))`

Comment: yep, I agree but I mentioned loop here to add some more usabilities, not only concatenating strings, we can even do stuffs like computing, read data from other sources, do if-else inside loop and more

Answer (score 1):

> IT returns number of objects are updated in table.

```
update_counts = ModelClass.objects.filter(name='bar').update(name="foo")
```

You can refer this link to get more information on bulk update and create.
[Bulk update and Create](https://voorloopnul.com/blog/doing-bulk-update-and-bulk-create-with-django-orm/)

Answer (score 0):

In Django 4.1 QuerySet.bulk_create() to update fields can be used. The update is executed when a row insertion fails uniqueness constraints.

> QuerySet.bulk_create() now supports updating fields when a row
> insertion fails uniqueness constraints. This is supported on MariaDB,
> MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite 3.24+.