# Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to update multiple rows in PostgreSQL in one statement. Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
UPDATE table 
SET 
 column_a = 1 where column_b = '123',
 column_a = 2 where column_b = '345'
```

Comment: I keep trying to find it on that page but I can't get it. I see where you can update multiple rows using one where statement, but I don't get how to update multiple rows each with it's own where statement. I also searched google and didn't find a real clear answer so I was hoping someone could provide a clear example on this.

Answer (score 777, accepted):

You can also use [`update ... from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) syntax and use a mapping table. If you want to update more than one column, it's much more generalizable:

```
update test as t set
    column_a = c.column_a
from (values
    ('123', 1),
    ('345', 2)  
) as c(column_b, column_a) 
where c.column_b = t.column_b;
```

You can add as many columns as you like:

```
update test as t set
    column_a = c.column_a,
    column_c = c.column_c
from (values
    ('123', 1, '---'),
    ('345', 2, '+++')  
) as c(column_b, column_a, column_c) 
where c.column_b = t.column_b;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2f536/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Also, one may have to specify a correct data type. An example with a date: `... from (values ('2014-07-21'::timestamp, 1), ('2014-07-20', 2), ...` Further details at the [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-values.html)

Comment: Works great, thank you for clarifying! The Postgres documentation for this makes for a bit of a confusing read.

Comment: that's cool!  did not expect to learn a new sql construct today

Comment: How dynamic build VALUES(...) ?  i.e. add 100 rows to VALUES().  Can it be an array or something?

Comment: @Charlie木匠 if you want to build it dynamically then you probably have data somewhere? why can't you just update it from the table?

Comment: @RomanPekar thanks for the reply.  Context: process 100 million rows, bulk fetch 100 rows each time, update 50 on table1, update 80 on table2, insert 70 on table3. for example. - 
The business logic is complicated, and cannot be done in Single SQL.  ^_^

Comment: @Charlie木匠 I'd say - make another question with example and some test data, it's a bit too much for a omment

Comment: Fyi, this is the most closest version I'm looking for. We can dynamically add rows to array.: ``` SELECT
    s.id, 
    s.marked_for_deletion,
    s.name
FROM unnest(
  array[
        ('2f888809-2777-524b-abb7-13df413440f5',true,'Salad fork'),
        ('f2924dda-8e63-264b-be55-2f366d9c3caa',false,'Melon baller'),
        ('d9ecd18d-34fd-5548-90ea-0183a72de849',true,'Fondue fork')
        ]::item[]
) s;
; ``` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517980/improving-a-function-that-upserts-based-on-an-input-array

Comment: What is the main reason of use `c`?

Comment: @ambigus9:  Presumably to give the columns names

Answer (score 168):

Based on the solution of @Roman, you can set multiple values:

```sql
update users as u set -- postgres FTW
  email = u2.email,
  first_name = u2.first_name,
  last_name = u2.last_name
from (values
  (1, 'hollis@weimann.biz', 'Hollis', 'Connell'),
  (2, 'robert@duncan.info', 'Robert', 'Duncan')
) as u2(id, email, first_name, last_name)
where u2.id = u.id;
```

Comment: This seems like his solution.. UPDATE FROM (VALUES...) WHERE. How is it only based?

Comment: I prefer this answer because the variable names make it easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: Wow. Precise and clear. I am trying to implement something like this in GoLang. So can I pass an array of structs in place for values? Something like this, `from (values $1)` Where $1 is an array of structs. In the above case, the strict would have id, first_name and last_name as properties.

Answer (score 44):

Yes, you can:

```
UPDATE foobar SET column_a = CASE
   WHEN column_b = '123' THEN 1
   WHEN column_b = '345' THEN 2
END
WHERE column_b IN ('123','345')
```

And working proof: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97c7ea/1

Comment: If you add `ELSE column_b` after the last `WHEN ? THEN ?` line then the column will be set to it's current value, thus preventing what MatheusQI said would happen.

Comment: That's not what he asked for.. he needs to update multiple cols, not set col A based on col B.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what OP asked for - only column_a needs updating (based on value of column_b), not multiple columns, right?

Comment: Works great with Postgre 12. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

For updating multiple **rows** in a single query, you can try this

```
UPDATE table_name
SET 
column_1 = CASE WHEN any_column = value and any_column = value THEN column_1_value end,
column_2 = CASE WHEN any_column = value and any_column = value THEN column_2_value end,
column_3 = CASE WHEN any_column = value and any_column = value THEN column_3_value end,
.
.
.
column_n = CASE WHEN any_column = value and any_column = value THEN column_n_value end
```

if you don't need additional condition then remove **`and`** part of this query

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you have an array of **IDs** and equivalent array of **statuses** - here is an example how to do this with a static SQL (a sql query that doesn't change due to different values) of the arrays :

```
drop table if exists results_dummy;
create table results_dummy (id int, status text, created_at timestamp default now(), updated_at timestamp default now());
-- populate table with dummy rows
insert into results_dummy
(id, status)
select unnest(array[1,2,3,4,5]::int[]) as id, unnest(array['a','b','c','d','e']::text[]) as status;

select * from results_dummy;

-- THE update of multiple rows with/by different values
update results_dummy as rd
set    status=new.status, updated_at=now()
from (select unnest(array[1,2,5]::int[]) as id,unnest(array['a`','b`','e`']::text[]) as status) as new
where rd.id=new.id;

select * from results_dummy;

-- in code using **IDs** as first bind variable and **statuses** as the second bind variable:
update results_dummy as rd
set    status=new.status, updated_at=now()
from (select unnest(:1::int[]) as id,unnest(:2::text[]) as status) as new
where rd.id=new.id;
```

Answer (score 6):

Came across similar scenario and the CASE expression was useful to me.

```
UPDATE reports SET is_default = 
case 
 when report_id = 123 then true
 when report_id != 123 then false
end
WHERE account_id = 321;
```

Reports - is a table here, account_id is same for the report_ids mentioned above. The above query will set 1 record (the one which matches the condition) to true and all the non-matching ones to false.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to other answers, comments and documentation, the datatype cast can be placed on usage. This allows an easier copypasting:

```
update test as t set
    column_a = c.column_a::number
from (values
    ('123', 1),
    ('345', 2)  
) as c(column_b, column_a) 
where t.column_b = c.column_b::text;
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by @zero323 works great on Postgre 12. In case, someone has multiple values for `column_b` (referred in OP's question)

```
UPDATE conupdate SET orientation_status = CASE
   when id in (66934, 39) then 66
   when id in (66938, 49) then 77
END
WHERE id IN (66934, 39, 66938, 49)
```

In the above query, `id` is analogous to `column_b`; `orientation_status` is analogous to `column_a` of the question.

Answer (score 2):

@Roman thank you for the solution, for anyone using node, I made this utility method to pump out a query string to update n columns with n records.

Sadly it only handles n records with the same columns so the recordRows param is pretty strict.

```js
const payload = {
  rows: [
    {
        id: 1,
        ext_id: 3
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        ext_id: 3
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        ext_id: 3
    } ,
        {
        id: 4,
        ext_id: 3
    } 
  ]
};

var result = updateMultiple('t', payload);

console.log(result);
/*
qstring returned is:

UPDATE t AS t SET id = c.id, ext_id = c.ext_id FROM (VALUES (1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3)) AS c(id,ext_id) WHERE c.id = t.id
*/



function updateMultiple(table, recordRows){
  var valueSets = new Array();
  var cSet = new Set();
  var columns = new Array();
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(recordRows.rows)) {
    var groupArray = new Array();
    for ( const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(recordRows.rows[key])){    
      if(!cSet.has(key2)){
        cSet.add(`${key2}`);
        columns.push(key2);
      }
      groupArray.push(`${value2}`); 
    }
    valueSets.push(`(${groupArray.toString()})`);
  }
  var valueSetsString = valueSets.join();  
  var setMappings = new String();
  for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
    var fieldSet = columns[i];
    
      setMappings += `${fieldSet} = c.${fieldSet}`;
      if(i < columns.length -1){
        setMappings += ', ';
      }
  }
  var qstring = `UPDATE ${table} AS t SET ${setMappings} FROM (VALUES ${valueSetsString}) AS c(${columns}) WHERE c.id = t.id`;
  return qstring;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the accepted answer is entirely correct. It is order dependent. Here is an example that will not work correctly with an approach from the answer.

```
create table xxx (
    id varchar(64),
    is_enabled boolean
);

insert into xxx (id, is_enabled) values ('1',true);
insert into xxx (id, is_enabled) values ('2',true);
insert into xxx (id, is_enabled) values ('3',true);

UPDATE public.xxx AS pns
        SET is_enabled         = u.is_enabled
            FROM (
            VALUES
         (
            '3',
            false
         ,
            '1',
            true
         ,
            '2',
            false
         )
        ) AS u(id, is_enabled)
            WHERE u.id = pns.id;

select * from xxx;
```

So the question still stands, is there a way to do it in an order independent way?

**---- after trying a few things this seems to be order independent**

```
UPDATE public.xxx AS pns
        SET is_enabled         = u.is_enabled
            FROM (
            SELECT '3' as id, false as is_enabled UNION
            SELECT '1' as id, true as is_enabled UNION
            SELECT '2' as id, false as is_enabled
         ) as u
            WHERE u.id = pns.id;
```

Comment: I guess there is a mistake with parentheses in the `VALUES` part of your query. It should be ` VALUES
           ('2', false),
           ('1', true),
           ('3', false)` and then it works fine