# Update multiple rows in same query using mapping table in Postgres 8.4

Tags: sql, postgresql

In question [Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql) Roman Peckar gave an answer similar to this; I have modified it for the purpose of my question:

```
update test as t set
  column_a = c.column_a,
  column_b = c.column_b
from (values
  ('123', bytea1),   
  ('345', bytea2)  
) as c(column_a, column_b) 
where c.column_a = t.column_a;
```

In my case table test has a column of type bytea, say column_b. However, this does not work as c.column_b is of type text and thus an error is produced saying there is no conversion from text to bytea and hinting to use a cast. Well, using a cast does not help either as another error occurs about encoding referring to a LATIN encoding. I apologise for the imprecise reporting of the errors but I do not presently have access to the machine on which this work was carried out.

It seems that the default type of the c.column_b is text. Cannot the type of a column be dictated in the 'as' clause say, 'as c(column_a, column_b type bytea)' or in some other way?  If not I assume I must resort to using some binary string function which seems a bit inelegant to say the least.

Comment: it would be great to see sqlfiddle.com example, so it would be easy for us to create working solution

Comment: @Roman Pekar: Well, you could of told me of sqlfiddle before this! :-). I'm just a poor C++ programmer having to deal with sql yet again. OK, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/11bb0/2 for the error. So we use a cast, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a0ba6/3 ok, no error, that's because we are entering a properly escaped bytea value. But, with this last query my code is sending a stream of raw byte data and I'm getting an error that moans about the locale (LATIN1 irc) and cannot convert the raw bytes. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Because `text` type is for text. It needs properly encoded text in your client encoding and which can be saved with no data loss in your server encoding (so for example in `latin1` no `“` or `€`, as characters like this can not be saved using this encoding).

So if you need to save text, which can contain characters outside of `latin1` (like anything typed to a web form) you'd need to change database encoding to `utf-8`. Or, as a last resort, use `encode(data,'base64')`.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. I am saving bytea data to column_b, type bytea, of table test via column_b, type text (so the error is telling me), of 'table' c. If I could declare the type of column_b of table c as bytea then there would be no problem (I hope to believe!).

Comment: [Data casted to bytea in your SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/11bb0/1/0) works.

Comment: It does, as I have explained above in my reply to Roman Pekar's comment. It does not work when I am sending that SQL statement with data that can contain any character i.e. binary data.