# UPDATE multiple rows from multiple params in nodejs/pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I'm using NodeJS and pg with a PostgreSQL database as backend.
Running single queries with Client.query works fine.

However, I've got a challenge which I can solve in a simple and elegant way.

I would like to run:

```
UPDATE portfolios SET votes = $1 WHERE id = $2
```

from an array/list of:

```
[{votes: 5, id: 1}, {votes: 15, id: 1}, {votes: 25, id: 2}]
```

Can it be done in a single Client.query (or similar with pg), so I don't have to make a "for () { ... }"?

Comment: Duplicate of [Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver must pass the query to Postgresql in this final shape:

```
update portfolios p
set votes = s.votes
from unnest(array[(5, 1), (15, 1), (25, 2)]) s (votes int, id int)
where p.id = s.id
```

So pass this query to the driver:

```
update portfolios p
set votes = s.votes
from unnest($1) s (votes int, id int)
where p.id = s.id
```

with an appropriate array as parameter.

Notice that if you string build it yourself in instead of letting the driver do it you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I see. Is there an easy way to convert "[{votes: 5, id: 1}, {votes: 15, id: 1}, {votes: 25, id: 2}]" into a correct array, as it seems UNNEST doesn't accept list of objects?

Comment: It seems as if I'm not allowed to map the array for returning tuples:
my_array = my_array.map(function(e) { return tuple(e.votes, e.id); })

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to solve your problem with the tuples in JS?