# Convert object array to array compatible for nodejs/pg/unnest

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, postgresql

In regards to [UPDATE multiple rows from multiple params in nodejs/pg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048772/update-multiple-rows-from-multiple-params-in-nodejs-pg), I need to run the following:

```
update portfolios p
set votes = s.votes
from unnest(array[(5, 1), (15, 1), (25, 2)]) s (votes int, id int)
where p.id = s.id
```

where my array in unnest is $1, as follows:

```
update portfolios p
set votes = s.votes
from unnest($1) s (votes int, id int)
where p.id = s.id
```

However, my array originally consist of objects, as:

```
[{votes: 5, id: 1}, {votes: 15, id: 1}, {votes: 25, id: 2}]
```

I've tried to convert it with:

```
my_array = my_array.map(function(e) { return tuple(e.votes, e.id); });
```

But that fails.

I need to correct compatible array with values for use with pg and Client.query.

How can I convert my array of objects to respect javascript and postgresql unnest?

Comment: Why are you needing to make this single `update` statement happen; why not run multiple `update` statements?

Comment: I'm using nodejs with pg which doesn't support multiple queries without making a manual loop between all statements - apparently. If other solution is available I'm all ears.

Comment: How does it fail? Is there a way to output the query that is being fed to Postgresql?

Comment: If it is not possible to get the output from the driver it is possible to see it in the Postgresql log.

Comment: I'm getting error 42804 "enforce_generic_type_consistency" from PostgreSQL if I keep my [{...}, {...}...] format.

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to use multiple queries you would have to loop through all the values and kick off one `update` statement for each value. But, can you explain why that isn't a reasonable solution?

Comment: @CarlTashian: That is reasonable but not optimal mainly because each update will be a round trip to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You could send your JSON string as is, and have PostgreSQL deal with it:

```
update portfolios p
set votes = s.votes
from (
  select (e->>'votes')::int as votes, (e->>'id')::int as id
  from (select (regexp_replace($1, '"\1"', 'g'))::jsonb as jarr) j
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(jarr) e
  ) s
where p.id = s.id;
```

Where `$1` is `[{votes: 5, id: 1}, {votes: 15, id: 1}, {votes: 25, id: 2}]', '([a-z]+)` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

[@Ziggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37063739/131874) idea to pass JSON can work although the ideal would be to make the driver adapt your array. This is the final query the driver must pass to Postgresql

```
update portfolios p
set votes = s.votes
from (
    select (a->>'votes')::int as votes, (a->>'id')::int as id
    from (
        select jsonb_array_elements(a) as a
        from (values ('[{"votes": 5, "id": 1}, {"votes": 15, "id": 1}]'::jsonb)) s(a)
    ) s
) s
where p.id = s.id
```

And the query to pass to the driver:

```
update portfolios p
set votes = s.votes
from (
    select (a->>'votes')::int as votes, (a->>'id')::int as id
    from (
        select jsonb_array_elements(a) as a
        from (values (($1)::jsonb)) s(a)
    ) s
) s
where p.id = s.id
```

The `$1` parameter must be jsonified with something like `JSON.stringify`:

```
var a = JSON.stringify(my_array_of_objects);
```