# SQL statement for multiple row UPDATE in nodejs using node-pg library

Tags: node.js, postgresql

My question is the same as [UPDATE multiple rows from multiple params in nodejs/pg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048772/update-multiple-rows-from-multiple-params-in-nodejs-pg) however I face the issue the question author pointed out in the comments.

Basically, I want to perform a multi-row update and have such an array of objects like

```
const arr = [
  { image_id: 1, image_url: "xyz.com/image" }
]
```

Now I want to use that array to generate the SQL statement but just like the author in the link above, I don't know how to make an array of objects into an array of tuples like SQL expects.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked but I had to change my data structure to:

```
{
    "images": ["xyz.com/image"],
    "ids": [2]
}
```

```
UPDATE collection_images as ci 
SET image_url = new.image_url 
FROM (SELECT UNNEST($1::VARCHAR[]) as image_url, UNNEST($2::INT[]) as image_id) as new
WHERE ci.id = new.image_id
RETURNING *;
```

But I'm still wondering whether there's a way without changing the  orignal data structure

Comment: note this wouldn't return all the updated rows. the `RETURNING *` at the end would only return the last modified row.