# PostgreSQL multi-row updates in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

As i already found here [On Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql) it is possible to update multiple rows in one query by doing something like this

```
update test as t set
    column_a = c.column_a,
    column_c = c.column_c
from (values
    ('123', 1, '---'),
    ('345', 2, '+++')  
) as c(column_b, column_a, column_c) 
where c.column_b = t.column_b;
```

special thanks to @Roman Pekar for the clear answer.

Now i'm trying to merge this way of updating with querying to a postgreSQL database in NodeJS.

Here is a snipped of my code:

```
var requestData = [
    {id: 1, value: 1234}
    {id: 2, value: 5678}
    {id: 3, value: 91011}
]


client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

client.query(buildStatement(requestData), function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.json(result.rows);

    client.end(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
});


var buildStatement = function(requestData) {
var params = [];
var chunks = [];

for(var i = 0; i < requestData.length; i++) {

    var row = requestData[i];
    var valuesClause = [];

    params.push(row.id);
    valuesClause.push('$' + params.length);
    params.push(row.value);
    valuesClause.push('$' + params.length);

    chunks.push('(' + valuesClause.join(', ') + ')');

}

return {
    text: 'UPDATE fit_ratios as f set ratio_budget = c.ratio_budget from (VALUES ' +  chunks.join(', ') + ') as c(ratio_label, ratio_budget) WHERE c.ratio_label = f.ratio_label', values: params
        }
}
```

i don't get an error but it doesn't update my table, i don't really know what goes wrong here. Perhaps a syntax error in my query code? I just don't find any specific examples of multiple row querying when updating in NodeJS pg package

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The example below is based on library [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), and its method [helpers.update](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update):

```
// library initialization, usually placed in its own module:
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({
    capSQL: true // capitalize all generated SQL
});

const db = pgp(/*your connection details*/);

// records to be updated:
const updateData = [
    {id: 1, value: 1234},
    {id: 2, value: 5678},
    {id: 3, value: 91011}
];

// declare your ColumnSet once, and then reuse it:
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['?id', 'value'], {table: 'fit_ratios'});

// generating the update query where it is needed:
const update = pgp.helpers.update(updateData, cs) + ' WHERE v.id = t.id';
//=> UPDATE "fit_ratios" AS t SET "value"=v."value"
//   FROM (VALUES(1,1234),(2,5678),(3,91011))
//   AS v("id","value") WHERE v.id = t.id

// executing the query:
await db.none(update);
```

This method of generating multi-row updates can be characterized as:

- very fast, as it relies on type [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) that implements smart caching for query generation
- completely safe, as all data types are going through the library's query formatting engine to make sure everything is formatted and escaped correctly.
- very flexible, due to advanced [ColumnConfig](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.ColumnConfig) syntax supported for the columns definition.
- very easy to use, due to the simplified interface implemented by [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

---

Note that we use `?` in front of column `id` to indicate that the column is part of the condition, but not to be updated. For complete column syntax see class [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) and [ColumnConfig](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.ColumnConfig) structure.

---

Related question: [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

Comment: where is the v and t coming from in v.id = t.id?

Comment: @dbainbridge From [helpers.update](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update) documentation, if you just follow the links provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I did accept the answer from @vitaly-t, as he taught me to use a better and faster library [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) and it did solve my problem. (period)

But to answer my own question for the people who could end up with the same problem and want to stay with the library [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg), here is where i made the mistake (it's just syntax)

In my original code i had this line at the end

```
return {
    text: 'UPDATE fit_ratios as f set ratio_budget = c.ratio_budget from (VALUES ' +  chunks.join(', ') + ') as c(ratio_label, ratio_budget) WHERE c.ratio_label = f.ratio_label', values: params
        }
}
```

The first time i saw this it was hard to understand so it was very easy to make some mistakes. changing this line of code to what you see underneath fixed my original problem to

```
return {
    text: 'UPDATE fit_ratios as f set ratio_budget = c.value from (VALUES ' +  chunks.join(', ') + ') as c(id, value) WHERE c.id = f.ratio_id',
                values: params
}
```

I just missed by using column names instead of using the keys of my object. (e.g. c.ratio_label to c.id, ...)

Comment: isnt this prone to SQLi?