# Type error in Nodejs and Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node.js-pg

I'm generating a dynamic update query based on a list of provided objects for postgres. This is what my query looks like:

```
update loan_item_assignment as t set id = c.id, dateselectionid = c.dateselectionid, loanitemid = c.loanitemid, active = c.active, type = c.type from (values ( $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 ), ( $6, $7, $8, $9, $10 ), ( $11, $12, $13, $14, $15 ), ( $16, $17, $18, $19, $20 ), ( $21, $22, $23, $24, $25 ), ( $26, $27, $28, $29, $30 ), ( $31, $32, $33, $34, $35 ), ( $36, $37, $38, $39, $40 ) ) as c( id, dateselectionid, loanitemid, active, type ) where c.id = t.id returning *
```

And here's the values list I'm giving it:

```
[ 7,
35,
3,
true,
'normal',
8,
35,
4,
true,
'normal',
1,
35,
6,
true,
'normal',
2,
35,
7,
true,
'normal',
3,
35,
8,
true,
'normal',
5,
35,
10,
true,
'normal',
4,
35,
11,
true,
'normal',
6,
35,
12,
true,
'normal' ]
```

As far as I can tell, the values match up correctly. This is the error I'm seeing:

```
{ [error: operator does not exist: text = integer]
name: 'error',
length: 195,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42883',
detail: undefined,
hint: 'No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.',
position: '448',
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'parse_oper.c',
line: '726',
routine: 'op_error' }
```

And this is the code that's ultimately running the query:

```
var performQuery = function(text, values, cb) {
   pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
     client.query(text, values, function(err, result) {
       done();
       if (!result) {
         console.log(err);
         cb([], err);
       } else {
         cb(result.rows, err);
       }
     })
   });

}
```

And here is the table definition:

```
Table "public.loan_item_assignment"
Column      |  Type   |                             Modifiers                             | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
id              | integer | not null default nextval('loan_item_assignment_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
dateselectionid | integer |                                                                   | plain    |              | 
loanitemid      | integer |                                                                   | plain    |              | 
active          | boolean |                                                                   | plain    |              | 
type            | text    |                                                                   | extended |              | 
Indexes:
"loan_item_assignment_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
"loan_item_assignment_dateselectionid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (dateselectionid) REFERENCES date_selection(id)
"loan_item_assignment_loanitemid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (loanitemid) REFERENCES loan_item(id)
```

Comment: As the error says, you have a type mismatch somewhere. You are assigning an integer to a field that is text.

Comment: As my examples show, all of the data types in my array match up properly with the columns in data type.

Comment: can you show definition of your table?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the main question

Comment: Proper way of doing it: [PostgreSQL multi-row updates in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119922/postgresql-multi-row-updates-in-node-js).

Comment: @vitaly-t: that looks perfect, I'll try that. Do I use this library in conjuction with "pg" or is it a replacement?

Comment: @Evan `node-postgres` is the underlying driver.

Answer (score 1):

Vitaly-t's comment on my answer is the solution - to use the [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library to generate the query, and specifically method [helpers.update](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update) for generating multi-row update queries, as shown in [PostgreSQL multi-row updates in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119922/postgresql-multi-row-updates-in-node-js).