# Npgsql C# multi row/value insert

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I've been looking at the PostGres multi row/value insert which looks something like this in pure SQL:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (1,2,3), (4,5,6)....
```

The reason I wan to use this is I have a lot of data to insert that is arriving via a queue, which I'm batching into 500/1000 record inserts at a time to improve performance.

However, I have been unable to find an example of doing this from within C#, everything I can find is adding only a single records parameter at a time, then executing, which is too slow.

I have this working using Dapper currently, but I need to expand the SQL to an upsert (insert on conflict update) which everything I have found indicated Dapper can't handle.  I have found evidence the Postgres can handle upsert and multi valued in a single [action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647600/postgresql-multi-value-upserts).

Tom

Answer (score 3):

I didn't get your question completely right. But for bulk insert in Postgresql, [this is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38690785/999809)

It gives an example for inserting multiple records from a list (RecordList) into table (user_data.part_list) :

```
using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport(
"copy user_data.part_list from STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"))
{
    foreach (var record in RecordList)
    {
        writer.StartRow();
        writer.Write(record.UserId);
        writer.Write(record.Age, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
        writer.Write(record.HireDate, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date);
    }

    writer.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Copy is nice, but it cannot use `ON CONFLICT` things

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert many records efficiently, you probably want to take a look at [Npgsql's bulk copy API](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html), which doesn't use SQL and is the most efficient option available.

Otherwise, there's nothing special about inserting two rows rather than one:

```cs
insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (@p1_1,@p1_2,@p1_3), (@p2_1,@p2_2,@p_3)....
```

Simply add the parameters with the correct name and execute just as you would any other SQL.

Answer (score 2):

`COPY` is the fastest way but does not work if you want to do UPSERTS with an `ON CONFLICT ...` clause.

If it's necessary to use `INSERT`, ingesting `n` rows (with possibly varying `n` per invocation) can be elegantly done using `UNNEST` like

```sql
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ..., coln) SELECT UNNEST(@p1), UNNEST(@p2), ... UNNEST(@pn);
```

The parameters `p` then need to be an array of the matching type. Here's an example for an array of ints:

```cs
new NpgsqlParameter()
{
 ParameterName = "p1",
 Value = new int[]{1,2,3},
 NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Integer
}
```