# Does pg-promise do DISCARD?

Tags: pg-promise

Based on this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250582/connection-pool-using-pg-promise) regarding pg-promise, when an existing connection/session is returned by request A to the pool and being re-used by a totally diff request B. Would pg-promise automatically do [DISCARD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html) so B won't see anything left by A? If not, can I issue it manually using pg-promise?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would pg-promise automatically do `DISCARD`?

No.

> Can I issue it manually using pg-promise?

Yes, but for individual queries it would do you no good, because those control connection by themselves, so you would not even know which session you are discarding.

I can see when this might be of use only inside a `task` or `tx` methods, but there you can easily add your own `DISCARD` query at the end, if needed.

```js
await db.task(async t => {

    // do your things here...

    // then run discard at the end, if needed:
    await t.none('DISCARD $1:value', ['PLANS']);
});
```

Comment: "I can see when this might be of use only inside a task or tx methods, but there you can easily just add your own DISCARD query at the end." Haven't used pg-promise, would you throw a quick Node sample of `task`?

Comment: @Jeb50 There ;)

Comment: If task is expected to return something, say a `select from myfunc()`, then `DISCARD` must proceed the `return` as:
`db.task(async t =>
        {
            await t.none('DISCARD $1:value', ['TEMP']);
            return t.any('select * from myfunc()');  // return is needed.
        })...`

Comment: @Jeb It's all consistent with the general promise usage (asynchronous paradigm). Whatever you return from the task callback, is what the task will resolve with.