# Update multiple columns and values node postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Using `node-postgres` I want to update columns in my user model, at present i have this

```
async function update_user_by_email(value, column, email){
  const sql = format('UPDATE users SET %I = $1,  WHERE email = $2', column);
  await pool.query(sql, [value, email]);
}
```

So I can do this

```
await  update_user_by_email(value, column_name, email_address);
```

However if I want to update multiple columns and values I am doing something very inefficient at the moment and calling that method x amount of times (i.e for each query)

```
await update_user_by_email(value, column_name, email_address);
await update_user_by_email(value_2, column_name_2, email_address);
await update_user_by_email(value_3, column_name_3, email_address);
```

How can I generate this with just one call to the database.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [PostgreSQL multi-row updates in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119922/postgresql-multi-row-updates-in-node-js)

Comment: Hey there, what library is the format() function you're using from?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here:

- node-postgres allows you to create [queries based on prepared statements](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#prepared-statements). (This builds on the native pg-sql [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html)).

  These are [recommended by postgres for populating a table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/populate.html) as a secondary option to using their `copy` command. You would end up doing more SQL statements (probably one per line), but the advantages of prepared statements are supposed to offset this somewhat.

  You can also combine this with [transactions](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions), also mentioned in the postgres "populate" link above.
- Another option is the approach taken by another library called [pg-promise (specifically helpers)](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update). The pg-promise helpers library literally builds sql statements (as a string) for the bulk insert/update statements. That way you can have a single statement to update/insert thousands of rows at a time.
- It's also possible (and relatively easy) to custom-build your own sql helpers, or to supplement pg-promise, by pulling structure data directly from `information_schema` `tables` and `columns` tables.

  One of the more tedious things about pg-promise is having to give it all the column names (and sometimes definitions, default values, etc), and if you're working with dozens or hundreds of separate tables, auto-generating this info directly from the database itself is probably simpler and more robust (you don't have to update arrays of column names every time you change your database)

NOTE: You **don't** need to use pg-promise to submit queries generated by their helpers library. Personally, I like node-postgres better for actual db communications, and typically only use the pg-promise helpers library for building those bulk SQL statements.

NOTE2: It's worth noting that pg-promise wrote their own SQL injection protection (by escaping single-quotes in values and double-quotes in table/column names). The same would need to be done in the third option. Whereas the prepared statements are natively protected from sql injection by the database server itself.