# Amazon Redshift syntax error when using UPDATE on specified VALUEs

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift

This is the query that I'm trying to run to update multiple rows by their ID in one single string. I'm using AWS Redshift (which is based on a very old version of PostgreSQL):

```
UPDATE promotion
   SET engagements = c.engagements
  FROM (VALUES (668, 73), (684, 135), (680, 73), (672, 76), (682, 94),
               (676, 4), (670, 81), (686, 104), (678, 1), (674, 0)
       ) AS c(id, engagements)
 WHERE c.id = promotion.id;
```

And this is the error being produced:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pg8000.core.ProgrammingError) (u'ERROR', 
u'42601', u'syntax error at or near ","', u'72', u'/home/ec2-
user/padb/src/pg/src/backend/parser/parser_scan.l', u'699', u'yyerror', u'', 
u'')
[SQL: 'UPDATE promotion SET engagements = c.engagements FROM (VALUES 
(668, 73), (684, 135), (680, 73), (672, 76), (682, 94), (676, 4), (670, 81), 
(686, 104), (678, 1), (674, 0)) AS c(id, engagements) WHERE c.id = 
promotion.id;']
```

EDIT: Using query format from answer here: [Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql#18799497)

Comment: @jarcobi889 Yes, fixed.

Comment: This is just a stab into the dark from looking at other's code online, but isn't the format usually to put VALUES on the outside of the enclosing parenthesis? : FROM VALUES ((668, 73), (684, 135)... etc.

Comment: From [unsupported Postgres features](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html): "*VALUES list used as constant tables*"

Comment: @jarcobi889 I got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql#18799497

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you explain better? this might be the answer.

Comment: @jstudios Good to know, thanks

Comment: That syntax is simply not supported in Redshift. The answer you are referring to is for Postgres, not for Redshift

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there an alternative/workaround?

Comment: Still, Redshift seems to support [`executemany` when you pass a list of dicts](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes): `.execute(table.insert(), [{...},...])`

Answer (score 0):

Redshift supports VALUES synthax only for inserts. However, if you really want to use something like this in a different context you can construct a statement with UNION:

```
UPDATE promotion
SET engagements = c.engagements
FROM (
    SELECT 668 as id, 73 as engagements
    UNION SELECT 684, 135
    UNION SELECT 680, 73
    -- to be continued
) c
WHERE c.id = promotion.id;
```

but I would better insert the records into a table and then `UPDATE FROM` that table