# psycopg2: Update multiple rows in a table with values from a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm attempting to update several rows at once using a tuple of tuples.
I figured out how to construct the sql statement from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql), but implementing it in `psycopg2` has proven to be more challenging.
Here's what I have:

```
c = db.cursor()

new_values = (("Richard",29),("Ronald",30))

sql = """UPDATE my_table AS t 
         SET name = e.name 
         FROM (VALUES %s) AS e(name, id) 
         WHERE e.id = t.id;"""

c.execute(sql, (new_values,))
```

The result is an error: `ProgrammingError: table "e" has 1 columns available but 2 columns specified`
This is because the `FROM` clause is being interpreted as:

```
FROM (VALUES (("Richard",29),("Ronald",30)))
```

instead of:

```
FROM (VALUES ("Richard",29),("Ronald",30))
```

I can work around this by doing the following but it seems unsafe:

```
import re
c = db.cursor()

sql = """UPDATE my_table AS t 
         SET name = e.name 
         FROM (VALUES %s) AS e(name, id) 
         WHERE e.id = t.id;"""
sql = c.mogrify(sql, (new_values,))

# Replace the first occurance of '((' with '('.
sql = sql.replace('((', '(',1)

# Replace the last occurance of '))' with ')'.
sql = re.sub(r'(.*)\)\)', r'\1)', sql)

sql = c.execute(sql)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query?rq=1#answer-30985541) pointed me in the right direction. [The documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) for `extras.execute_values` also contains a great example using the `UPDATE` clause.

```
c = db.cursor()
update_query = """UPDATE my_table AS t 
                  SET name = e.name 
                  FROM (VALUES %s) AS e(name, id) 
                  WHERE e.id = t.id;"""

psycopg2.extras.execute_values (
    c, update_query, new_values, template=None, page_size=100
)
```

Comment: ugh this seems so roundabout.  Anyone else feel like anytime something fails in `psycopg2` it's guaranteed to take over an hour of googling to find the exact syntax to make it work?  Like why the huge difference in syntax between a bulk insert and bulk update

Appreciate the answer, just venting

Comment: if someone has `connection already closed` error, try to move the `id` before `name`. It'll save you 3 days :)