# Bulk update via raw query in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typeorm, bulkupdate

How can I do bulk update via raw query in TypeORM?
For example we have model *User* with property *name*
How can I change names of few users in one transaction?

typeorm version: **0.2.7**
database: **postgress**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To bulk update, you can use update with set method, it is always recommended to not use raw queries when you can use orm functions.

```js
import {getConnection, In} from "typeorm";
const userIds = [1,2,3];

await getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update(User)
  .set({ isaSeniorCitizen: true })
  .where({ id: In(userIds) })
  .execute();
```

Comment: What difference between this and first answer?

Comment: It lets you update against multiple records: `.where({ id: In(userIds) })`. Since your question was regarding `how to bulk update`

Comment: But in this scenario subscribers are not working, any solutions for that? @aitchkhan

Answer (score 14):

Also you can update several rows with repository api this way:

```
await repository.update(
  {
    id: In([1,2,3,4,5]),
  },
  { selected: true },
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either use [QueryBuilder](https://typeorm.io/#/update-query-builder):

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

await getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update(User)
  .set({ firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw" })
  .where("id = :id", { id: 1 })
  .execute();
```

or `query()` method:

```
getRepository(User).query('UPDATE `users` SET firstName = 'Timber', lastName = 'Saw' WHERE id = 1')
```

For bulk updating obviously you can do `.where({ id: In(userIds) })` with QueryBuilder or `WHERE id IN (${userIds.join(',')})` with raw query.

Comment: I am not sure who does this query bulk updating?

Comment: sorry my question was "how" does this query bulk updating it?

Comment: Don't build query strings in TS! This is how you get SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

Updating multiple columns with different values is not supported. There is an open issue about this in the Typeorm repo: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7326

How to perform this using raw psql is shown in @Roman-Pekar's answer to [Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql).

Another "solution" would be to create a stored function in the postgres db and call that. In one of the comments to another similar question I show an example on how to do that: [typeorm efficient bulk update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64282704/typeorm-efficient-bulk-update/65426334#65426334)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way

```
import {getConnection } from "typeorm";
const userIds = [1,2,3];

await getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update(User)
  .set({ isaSeniorCitizen: true })
  .whereInIds(userIds)
  .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

the `getConnection()` method has been depreacted

so try this

```js
@Controller("/test")
export class TestController {

    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Users) private UsersRepository: Repository<Users>
    ) { }

    @Get()
    async test() {

        await this.UsersRepository
            .createQueryBuilder("updateUsers")
            .update(Users)
            .set({ name: 'michael scott' })
            .whereInIds([1, 2, 3])
            .execute();

    }

}
```