# typeorm efficient bulk update

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, typeorm

I have an update query using `typeorm` on a `postgresql` database, like the one below, which is performed on a list of 20+ items frequently (once every 30 sec). It takes approx. 12 seconds for the update, which is a lot for my limits.

```js
for (item of items) {
    await getConnection().createQueryBuilder().update(ItemEntity)
        .set({status: item.status, data: item.data})
        .whereInIds(item.id).execute();
}
```

Is it possible to perform such a bulk update in a single query, instead of iterating other the items? If so - how?

`item.status` and `item.data` are unique for each item.

Comment: When I've faced the same behavior I built a regular SQL query to update all items by one query and then execute it. I believe this is the most performant way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do a workaround for this through upsert

Using an array of data that is already on the db and using ON CONFLICT to update it.

```
const queryInsert = manager
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(Entity)
    .values(updatedEntities)
    .orUpdate(["column1", "column2", "otherEntityId"], "PK_table_entity")
    .execute();
```

will run something like:

```
INSERT INTO entity (
    "id", "column1", "column2", "otherEntityId"
) VALUES 
    ($1, $2, $3, $4), 
    ($5, $6, $7, $8), 
ON CONFLICT 
    ON CONSTRAINT "PK_table_entity" 
    DO UPDATE SET 
        "column1" = EXCLUDED."column1", 
        "column2" = EXCLUDED."column2", 
        "otherEntityId" = EXCLUDED."otherEntityId"
```

But you need to be aware that orUpdate does not support using Entity relations, you will need to pass the id column of a relation entity. It also doesnt do any manipulation for the naming strategy. Another problem is that it only works if you're not using @PrimaryGeneratedColumn for your pk (you can use @PrimaryColumn instead)

Answer (score 1):

Using pure psql this can be done as described in the answers to: [Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql)

However, the `UpdateQueryBuilder` from Typeorm does not support a `from` clause.
For now, I think that a raw query is the only way, i.e. `getManager().query("raw sql ...")`.

Comment: yeah did that with the raw query

Comment: Hi, could you share how did you do this ? I am still struggling with putting values in query.

Comment: @ZarghamKhan

This is one way to do it. 
Entitymanager calls stored function.

`await entityManager.query(\`SELECT public.f_transact(array[${str}]::public.type_transaction[])\`);`
f_transact is a stored function.
str is a array of values as such `('${v1}','${v2}','${v3}')`;
type_transaction is a type defined in my db. 
**Validation of the data is done in the application code.**