# Bulk Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sql-update, case

I'm looking to update multiple rows in PostgreSQL and Go in one statement. Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
UPDATE table 
SET column_a = "FINISH", 
    column_b = 1234 
WHERE id = '1',
    column_a = "UNFINISH", 
    column_b = 3124 
WHERE id = '2'
```

and is there an example, if executed in go language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In postgresql you can use the update-from-values approach described in the answers here: [Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql)

And in Go you can implement that like this:

```
func updateWithSlice(slice []T) error {
    var queryString = `UPDATE "table" AS t SET (
        "column_a"
        , "column_b"
    ) = (
        x."column_a"::text
        , x."column_b"::integer
    )
    FROM (VALUES` // `

    numColumns := 3 // the number of columns you want to update + 1 for the id column
    params := make([]interface{}, len(slice)*numColumns)
    for i, t := range slice {
        pos := i * numColumns

        params[pos+0] = t.ColumnA
        params[pos+1] = t.ColumnB
        params[pos+2] = t.Id

        queryString += `($` + strconv.Itoa(pos+1) +
            `,$` + strconv.Itoa(pos+2) +
            `,$` + strconv.Itoa(pos+3) +
            `),`
    }

    queryString = queryString[:len(queryString)-1] // drop last ","
    queryString += ` ) AS x (
        "column_a"
        , "column_b"
        , "id"
    )
    WHERE t."id" = x."id"::integer` // `

    _, err := db.Exec(queryString, params...)
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to do this in Postgres is using `UNNEST`. This lets you pass one parameter per column (rather than number of rows x number of columns). For your example, this would look like:

```
UPDATE table
SET
  column_a=bulk_query.updated_column_a,
  column_b=bulk_query.updated_column_b
FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
      ?::TEXT[],
      ?::TEXT[],
      ?::INT[]
    ) AS t(id, updated_column_a, updated_column_b)
  ) AS bulk_query
WHERE
  users.id=bulk_query.id
```

Then you can pass three parameters:

```
[
  ["1", "2"],
  ["FINISH", "UNFINISH"],
  [1234, 3124]
]
```

The great thing about this approach, is that you only need those 3 parameters no matter how many rows you want to update.

I've written more about this topic in this blog post: https://www.atdatabases.org/blog/2022/01/21/optimizing-postgres-using-unnest#update-multiple-records-to-different-values-in-a-single-query

Answer (score 2):

I am a fan of structuring this using a derived table:

```
UPDATE t
    SET column_a = v.column_a,
        column_b = v.column_b
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'FINISH', 1234),
                 (2, 'UNFINISH', 3124)
         ) v(id, column_a, column_b)
    WHERE v.id = t.id;
```

This makes it simple to add additional values -- both `id`s and columns -- without complicating the query.  It is less prone to accidental errors as well.

Comment: This was the best solutions for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
update mytable
set 
    column_a = case when id = 1 then 'FINISH' else 'UNFINISHED' end,
    column_b = case when id = 1 then 1234     else 3124 end
where id in (1, 2)
```

Rationale:

- the `where` clause filters only on the `id`s you want to `update`, which is more efficient (provided you have an index on `id` ), and simplifies the conditional logic
- `id` looks like a number, so it should be treated as such (ie, do not surround the literal values with quotes)
- literal strings must be surrounded with single quotes - double quotes stand for identifiers (such as column names)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE expression.

```
UPDATE table 
SET 
  column_a = CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN 'FINISH'
                  WHEN id = '2' THEN 'UNFINISH'
                  ELSE 'SOMETHING'
             END,
  column_b = CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN 1234
                  WHEN id = '2' THEN 3124
                  ELSE 0
             END;
```

Comment: This will also update every other row to `column_a = 'SOMETHING'` and 'coloumn_b = 0`.  I do not think that is the intent.