# PostgreSQL: update multiple records (handle NULL values)

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL and was looking for a way to update multiple records in a single query.
I found this solution: [Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql)

But this solution does not work when all rows to update should be updated with NULL value. Here is an example:

**Table definition**

```
create table person (id char(1), my_value smallint);
```

**populate**

```
insert into person values
   ('1', 1),
   ('2', NULL),
   ('3', 3)
;
```

**not working update**

```
update person as db_record_to_update set
   my_value = db_record_new.my_value
from (values
   ('1', NULL),
   ('2', NULL)
) as db_record_new(id, my_value) 
where db_record_new.id = db_record_to_update.id;
```

**Error I get**

```
DatatypeMismatch: column "my_value" is of type smallint but expression is of type text
LINE 3:    my_value = db_record_new.my_value
                      ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

**Question**

How can I execute multiple update with one / multiple fields all null ?

*Note*

- *the query is valid and works fine only if at least one my_value is non null. For instance this query works fine (same expet I replaced 1  NULL to 55):*

```
update person as db_record_to_update set
   my_value = db_record_new.my_value
from (values
   ('1', NULL),
   ('2', 55)
) as db_record_new(id, my_value) 
where db_record_new.id = db_record_to_update.id;
```

- *I am running this queries on a notebook with psychog2 in case it matters*

Comment: Use `('1', NULL::smalint)`

Comment: it works now, thank you !

Comment: Or if you don't want to do this for every value, ` db_record_new(id, my_value::int)` or `my_value = db_record_new.my_value::int`. Basically following `HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`. Since `NULL` can be anything you have to give the parser a hint about what 'type' of `NULL` you are trying to `INSERT/UPDATE`. Your second case worked because the `55` provided the type hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Postgres doesn't know the type of the `my_value` column in your `VALUES` expression, so it defaults them to `text`. You can avoid this by annotating at least one `NULL` value with the desired type `smallint`:

```
update person as db_record_to_update
set my_value = db_record_new.my_value
from (values
   ('1', NULL::smallint),
   ('2', NULL)
) as db_record_new(id, my_value) 
where db_record_new.id = db_record_to_update.id;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4f94e89a8cdcea7f136980673492497b))</sup>