# PostgreSQL - Does row locking depends on update syntax in transaction?

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I have a table called user_table with 2 columns: id (integer) and data_value (integer).

Here are two transactions that end up with the same results:

```
-- TRANSACTION 1

BEGIN;

UPDATE user_table 
SET data_value = 100
WHERE id = 0;

UPDATE user_table 
SET data_value = 200
WHERE id = 1;

COMMIT;

-- TRANSACTION 2

BEGIN;

UPDATE user_table AS user_with_old_value SET
    data_value = user_with_new_value.data_value
FROM (VALUES
    (0, 100),
    (1, 200)  
) AS user_with_new_value(id, data_value) 
WHERE user_with_new_value.id = user_with_old_value.id;

COMMIT;
```

I would like to know if there is a difference on the lock applied on the rows.

If I understand it correctly, transaction 1 will first lock user 0, then lock user 1, then free both locks.

But what does transaction 2 do ?
Does it do the same thing or does it do: lock user 0 and user 1, then free both locks ?

There is a difference because if i have two concurent transactions, if i write my queries as the first transaction, i might encounter deadlocks issues. But if I write my transactions like the second one, can I run into deadlocks issues ?

If it does the same thing, is there a way to write this transaction so that at the beginning of a transaction, before doing anything, the transaction checks for each rows it needs to update, waits until all this rows are not locked, then lock all rows at the same time ?

*links:*
*the syntax of the second transaction comes from: [Update multiple rows in same query using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both transactions lock the same two rows, and both can run into a deadlock. The difference is that the first transaction always locks the two rows in a certain order.

If your objective is to avoid deadlocks the first transaction is better: if you make a rule that any transaction must update the user with the lower `id` first, then no such two transactions can deadlock with each other (but they can still deadlock with other transactions that do not obey that rule).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not sure i understand it correctly: if both syntax do exactly the same thing, why would the first syntax be better than the second one ?

Comment: I tried to make that clearer.