# Updating many rows without a good WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, go, azure-sql-database, go-gorm

We have two databases tracking separate information about the same IRL phenomenon

```
db1 columns:
    Key -- Approx 250k values
    Name
    Data (possibly NULL)
```

.

```
db2 columns:
    Key
    ForeignKey --Not contiguous! Approx 100k values
    Data (definitely not NULL)
```

I am writing a program to continuously duplicate `Data` from db2 into db1

My current approach is something like:

```
foreach row in db2
    update db1.Data = db2.Data where db1.Key = db2.ForeignKey
    (Forgive the terrible pseudocode, I hope it gets the point across.)
```

That is - make 100k individual calls into db1 with new data. Every five minutes, to keep db1 reasonably up to date.

This feels like a fundamentally wrong approach. Once I have the data from db2, I feel like I should be able to write some single call into db1 that does the whole update in one go - but I have no idea how to do that.

Alternatively, I could read every row from db1 that I want to modify into memory, do the modifications, then write them back in one single write.

The technologies involved are

- db1: Microsoft Azure - SQL Server
- db2: Microsoft Azure - Azure Database for PostgreSQL Server
- Program: Go, using the gorm package and db drivers.

Comment: What is an "IRL phenomenon"? Would you mind giving us a data model ("create table" statements) and the SQL statements already there? And maybe the Go code.
Is it necessary to keep the data for db1 redundantly, or would a remote read do it too?
Is there a way to mark the data in db2 when it is updated? That would allow for a good WHERE condition.
My strategy would be to mark changes in db2 (timestamp), and update db1 with a single update through a foreign table.

Comment: `What is an "IRL phenomenon"?` - a thing that happens independently of software and databases - cars crossing a border, packages in flight, arrests across the nation. `is it necessary to keep the data for db1 redundantly` Yes that is rather the task I have been given - the current synthetic read (using graphql) is too slow. `Is there a way to mark the data in db2 when it is updated` unfortunately no. `update db1 with a single update through a foreign table` - is that possible when the tables are in databases on different servers?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql)? You may want to chop down the 100k id's into several operations though.

Comment: maybe try doing batch insert once you've read from one database and applied the changes. see: https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/764#issuecomment-685249471