# Using django orm to update a table without deleting relations

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, orm

I have this two related django models

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_nbr = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    item_nbr_desc = models.CharField(max_length=155)

class SetItem(models.Model):
    set_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, default='', max_length=12)
    set_nbr = models.IntegerField()
    items = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Im running an script (periodically) to read the `Item` table **from another database**, and use that dataframe to update the django database item table. I'm using the django orm framework to make the interface with the django database

`script.py`

```
from app.models import Item

item_table = pd.read_sql(__) 
item_table = some_transformations(item_table.copy())
#I remove all the Items that will be updated 
Item.objects.filter(item_nbr__in=item_table.item_nbr.unique()).delete()
item_table_records = item_table.to_dict('records')
item_instances = []
fields = item_table.keys()
for record in item_table_records:
    kwargs = {
             field: record[field] for field in fields
             }
    item_instances.append(Item(**kwargs))
Item.objects.bulk_create(item_instances) # update the new rows
```

the problem is that the `setItem` table its deleted each time that I delete the Items related (because the `on_delete=models.CASCADE` behavior). I want to update the `items` not erasing the `setItem`  related rows, and i don't want to change the `on_delete` default behavior because only in this script I need to upload a whole table, its possible that i want to delete a `Item` in another context and i hope that the cascade behavior is working. what can i do? its there a bulk update function that might perform a non-destructive update of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the `@transaction.atomic` [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly), and using the `save()` method you will have a "batch" update without the need to delete the item table.

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def item_update(item_table):
    items_by_pk = Item.objects.in_bulk(item_table.item_nbr.values)
    for record in item_table.to_dict('records'):
        item = items_by_pk[record['item_nbr']]
        for field, value in record:
           setattr(item, field, value)
        item.save()
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661253/how-to-bulk-update-with-django#comment67696491_28551658)

Answer (score 1):

You can update the items one by one:

```
items_by_pk = Item.objects.in_bulk(item_table.item_nbr.values)
for record in item_table.to_dict('records'):
    item = items_by_pk[record['item_nbr']]
    for field, value in record:
        setattr(item, field, value)
    item.save()
```

Comment: the `items_by_pk = Item.objects.in_bulk(item_table.item_nbr)` gives me a `ValueError`. 
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: the performance its really poor!! considering that my `Item` table has more than 300K registers. I need a "bulk" solution :(

Comment: I just fixed the ValueError. You need to make sure to batch the queries together in transactions, but it's still going to be slow. Can you write a raw SQL query that would be faster?

Comment: Im trying that aproach reading the answers over this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661253/how-to-bulk-update-with-django