# Django Queryset .save() is slow

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to perform some operations over a queryset and then  use the .save() on each model instance, but it seems to be slow.

```
for clock in Clocks.objects.filter(status=True):
     # actions here
     clock.save()
```

Is this correct or is there any other method to be used when updating a model instance within a queryset.

Do you think [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)
can perform this any better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'bulk update' with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661253/how-to-bulk-update-with-django).

Comment: Try to do the update on the database, here this will result in *2N* queries, with *N* the number of `Clocks` with `status=True`.

Comment: @YellowShark that will update all records with the same value, and that is not what I need :(

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah I guess that will be the only way, I was just trying to check all posibilities before performing a raw query.

Comment: @erick.chali: if the operation is rather "simple" you can use an SQL expression.