# How to perform bulk update instead of updating each row?

Tags: python, django

I am new to the python and Django world. I don't know if there is a better way of doing the following:

```
#retrieve account row, correct soc code and save record.
for i in xrange(0,len(accIdList)):
    acc = account.objects.filter(id=accIdList[i])[0]
    acc.soc = getAccSocCode(acc)
    acc.save()

def getAccSocCode(acc):
    #apply business rules on acc
    # and return new soc code
    return socCode
```

This is what my code is doing now:

1. Get account row from the database
2. Pass account object to a separate method
3. This method performs some business rules and returns new soc code
4. Update account row

Here, I am updating each account row separately, is there a better way to this like below:

```
#retrieve account row, correct soc code and save record.
accList = []
for i in xrange(0,len(accIdList)):
    acc = account.objects.filter(id=accIdList[i])[0]
    acc.soc = getAccSocCode(acc)
    accList.append(acc)
accList.save()
```

I tried the above code but it throws an error saying `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'save'`

In short, how to perform bulk update in Django?

Answer (score 1):

Use F objects - see: [How to 'bulk update' with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661253/how-to-bulk-update-with-django).

Even if you are saving one by one you should change your code to something like:

```
for id in accIdList:
    acc = account.objects.get(id)
    acc.soc = getAccSocCode(acc)
    acc.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at that answer and seems like it will work only if all the rows will have same value. In my case, each row will have different value.