# How to Save all models changes in one query on Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I try to modify many instance of some model (like `User` model), and this changes is different (I don't want to use update `QuerySet` method and not works for my scenario).

For example some user need to change `first_name` and some user need to change `last_name` and get users like : `all_user = User.objects.all()`

I think if I use save method for each instance after change, Django sent one query for save that!

How can I save all changes to database in one query instead of use foreach on models and save that one by one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 'bulk update' with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661253/how-to-bulk-update-with-django)

Answer (score 3):

Given the comment from @iklinac, I would thoroughly recommend implementing django's own approach to bulk updates detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

It's quite similar to my original answer, below, but it looks like the functionality is now built in.

```
# bulk_update(objs, fields, batch_size=None)
>>> objs = [
...    Entry.objects.create(headline='Entry 1'),
...    Entry.objects.create(headline='Entry 2'),
... ]
>>> objs[0].headline = 'This is entry 1'
>>> objs[1].headline = 'This is entry 2'
>>> Entry.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['headline'])
```

*Original answer*

There's a package called [django-bulk-update](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update) which is similar to bulk create which is builtin to django.

An example of where I use this, is part of an action in an admin class;

```py
@admin.register(Token)
class TokenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'type'
    )

    actions = (
        'set_type_charity',
    )

    def set_type_charity(self, request, queryset):
        for token in queryset:
            token.type = Token.Type.CHARITY

        bulk_update(
            queryset,
            update_fields=['type', 'modified'],
            batch_size=1000
        )
```

Usage, taken from their readme;

With manager:

```py
import random
from django_bulk_update.manager import BulkUpdateManager
from tests.models import Person

class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = BulkUpdateManager()

random_names = ['Walter', 'The Dude', 'Donny', 'Jesus']
people = Person.objects.all()
for person in people:
  person.name = random.choice(random_names)

Person.objects.bulk_update(people, update_fields=['name'])  # updates only name column
Person.objects.bulk_update(people, exclude_fields=['username'])  # updates all columns except username
Person.objects.bulk_update(people)  # updates all columns
Person.objects.bulk_update(people, batch_size=50000)  # updates all columns by 50000 sized chunks
```

With helper:

```py
import random
from django_bulk_update.helper import bulk_update
from tests.models import Person

random_names = ['Walter', 'The Dude', 'Donny', 'Jesus']
people = Person.objects.all()
for person in people:
  person.name = random.choice(random_names)

bulk_update(people, update_fields=['name'])  # updates only name column
bulk_update(people, exclude_fields=['username'])  # updates all columns except username
bulk_update(people, using='someotherdb')  # updates all columns using the given db
bulk_update(people)  # updates all columns using the default db
bulk_update(people, batch_size=50000)  # updates all columns by 50000 sized chunks using the default db
```

Comment: There is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update from Django 2.2

Comment: @iklinac I completely missed the introduction of that! Thanks.