# Best practice for calling save() many times

Tags: python, django

When calling save many times, it works but takes a few minuts.

```
num = 100000
for i in range(num):
    lu = sm.UserType(type_id=1)
    lu.save()
```

In my understanding save exec the `SQL`.

So if I can put `save` together, it takes a shorter time.

Is there any practice for this purpose?

Comment: If you do not have any post_save/pre_save signals or custom save method you could use bulk_create

Comment: Use [bulk updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12661253/3929826) or a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with [**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

```
num = 100000

sm.UserType.objects.bulk_create([
    sm.UserType(type_id=1)
    for i in range(num)
])
```

This will for most databases create all records with *one* query, except for SQLite, that will create the objects in batches of 999 items.