# Name 'Group' is not defined

Tags: python, django

**Django 1.11**

**Python 3.6.1**

For my project is to be deployed, I will have to predefine some things. Namely, I'll need a couple of groups for users.

So, I made a directory "deployment" and placed it next to the project's directory.

When a new database will be created, I'll just execute:

```
python manage.py shell < ../deployment/initialize_project.py
```

This code **works:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Group.objects.create(name="commentator") # Can only comment.

Group.objects.create(name="contributor") # Can add, change and delete
                                         # objects.
```

This code **does not**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


def initialize_roles():

    Group.objects.create(name="commentator") # line 6

    Group.objects.create(name="contributor") 


initialize_roles() # line 12
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 101, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in initialize_roles
NameError: name 'Group' is not defined
```

I marked line 6 and 12 in the code above (as inline comments).

I tried to use pdb.set_trace(), but the same error appear. As if pdb is not defined.

I also tried not to feed manage.py on initialize_project.py, but just run python manage.py shell and feed the code line by line. It worked perfectly.

Could you give me a kick here?

**ADDED LATER**

This works:

```
def initialize_roles():
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
    Group.objects.create(name="commentator") # Can only comment.

    Group.objects.create(name="contributor") # Can add, change and delete
                                             # objects.

initialize_roles()
```

Comment: There's clearly something going on in the lines you've edited out. Do you redefine Group inside that function, by any chance?

Comment: No redefinition inside that function. I would say - to the best of my ability - that those lines are exactly as I give them here. I just copied them. In the whole file there is nothing else but a comment for the function.

Comment: Interesting! Does this work when manually copy-pasted the code in `python manage.py shell` . Imean `initialize_roles()` style which is not working

Comment: Being manually copied to the shell line by line, it works perfectly.

Comment: Why do you added the import inside the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar situation - this behavior is strange, indeed. It looks like inside this function, all the imports are missing (I checked that with dir() - it was empty), but I don't know why. Would be great if someone could answer that.

I don't think it's elegant to keep the script unwrapped by function, and as I was facing the same thing, I found this thread useful (danodonovan's answer): [Python Script from Django shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/how-to-execute-a-python-script-from-the-django-shell). What he suggests is to create `commands` subdir, and add a script to it (for instance `init_db`). Then you can easily run:

```
./manage.py init_db
```

This resolves problems stated in your question, but not answers why is it happening.
I hope that someone explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is more to what you're doing, this feels like something [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/) are meant to solve. If there is more to it, you can add [custom data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/writing-migrations/) as part of the initial set up process. That will avoid having to worry about when models are available to you.

Comment: Tom, the question was not about fixtures. This is strange behaviour of a python program, isn't it?