# Running python script inside a functional test in Django

Tags: python, django, functional-testing

The project that I'm recently working on load initial data by running a script:

```
python manage.py shell < add_initial_data.py
```

I'm making functional tests now and have to call this command to load initial data in the test database.

I'm trying to use `subprocess.call` and `call_command` to run that script but I can't find the option to redirect the script file to `shell`.

Is there a way to do that?

I've tried with

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'manage.py', 'shell', '<', 'add_initial_data.py'])
```

and

```
call_command('shell', '<', 'add_initial_data.py')
```

but gives error not recognizing `< add_initial_data.py`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching this from wrong angle. Django uses [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/) to load initial data. It is also supported in test cases [django test fixture loading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading)
If you are in python 3 and insist on your approach you might do

```
./manage.py shell <<EOF\ execfile('add_initial_data.py') \EOF
```

Comment: Thanks @Mazel. This project is loading initial data with running that script and using fixtures either. I can't merge the two approaches by now, so at the present I will run that script. But I didn't understand your answer. I need to run the script using `call_command` write? How to put the `<<EOF\ execfile('add_initial_data.py') \EOF` inside `call_command`, as `call_command` accepts options. Like `call_command('shell', ...)?

Comment: just paste it as is... or check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/executing-python-script-from-django-shell

Comment: Ok, the link in your comment solves the question using python built-in `exec` function. Specifically the `exec(open('add_initial-data.py').read())` command as I'm using python 3. Thank you.