# how to import all django models and more in a script?

Tags: python, django

I've put the following code at the top of my script file

```
 os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'momsite.conf.local.settings')
 django.setup()
```

Now I can import my django apps and run small snippets (to mainly test stuff)

I'd like to import all the models registered through `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`

I know https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions does this when running `manage.py shell_plus` it automatically imports all the models and more.

I'm looking at their code. not sure if I'll make sense out of it.

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/3355332238910f3f30a3921e604641562c79a0a8/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py#L137

at the moment, I'm doing the following, and I think it is importing models, but not available in the script somehow

```
 from django_extensions.management.shells import import_objects
 from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

 options = {}
 style = BaseCommand().style
 import_objects(options, style)
```

- edit.. answer adopted from dirkgroten

`import_objects` internally calls `from importlib import import_module` Apparently, we need to populate globals() with imported class

```
 options = {'quiet_load': True}
 style = BaseCommand().style

 imported_objects = import_objects(options, style)
 globals().update(imported_objects)
```

Comment: "Now I can import my django apps and run small snippets (to mainly test stuff)" => Note that you really don't need all this overhead for this, cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/how-to-execute-a-python-script-from-the-django-shell

Comment: "I'd like to import all the models registered through settings.INSTALLED_APPS" => looks like the part you want is here https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/3355332238910f3f30a3921e604641562c79a0a8/django_extensions/management/shells.py#L238 - everything around is some very generalized (and overcomplicated IMHO) stuff that tries to deal with every possible situation.

Comment: I've managed to do the importing, but thing is it is not imported... :( @brunodesthuilliers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you run `django.setup()`, do this:

```
from django.apps import apps
for _class in apps.get_models():
    if _class.__name__.startswith("Historical"): 
        continue
    globals()[_class.__name__] = _class
```

That will make all models classes available as globals in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `management` command. It will automagically load django() and everything.
Then in your command you simply start your command. `./manage.py mytest`

```
#myapp/management/commands/mytest.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from myapp.sometest import Mycommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'my test script'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        pass
        # parser.add_argument('poll_ids', nargs='+', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Mycommand.something(self)
```

which will call the actuall script:

```
#sometest.py
from .models import *
class Mycommand():
   def something(self):
       print('...something')
```