# Python: issues with watchdog.observers.join()

Tags: python, django, python-watchdog

I am currently working on a django project and trying to import models from a python source file

I typed `python manage.py shell < dummy_source.py` in cmd and it resulted in an error:

> observer.join()
>
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

However, when I just typed `python dummy_source.py`, it worked without any problems. I have gone online to find something useful but there are not any.

I would love to know why does this happen, thanks in advance.

Here is the content of dummy_source.py:

```
import os, time, sys
import subprocess as proc
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print("Created!")
        os.system('cmd /c "mkdir workspace"')
        print("Deleted!")
        os.system('cmd /c "rmdir /s /q workspace"')


event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path = 'media/submited_files', recursive = False)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Comment: You are using the django shell wrong. To import a script into django interactive shell follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/how-to-execute-a-python-script-from-the-django-shell

Comment: @CristianGabor Oh thank you for the useful link.