# Cannot run python script in Django

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I have an app called 'catalog', here's the model in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

    class Catalog(models.Model):
    
        brand = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        supplier = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        catalog_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        collection = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        season = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        size_group_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
        currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)
        target_area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to create one Catalog object but I don't want to do it using the admin panel or a form, so in the same app 'catalog' I've created `tools.py` which is just a script, it reads a csv file and create an istance of `Catalog()`.

```
from catalog.models import Catalog


def create_catalog(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
          f = f.readlines()
          catalog = Catalog(# all my keyword args)
          catalog.save()
```

I don't know if the script is fine but it's not important, my problem is when I try to run `tools.py` froom my IDE I get this error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I tried to run it from the shell with:

```
exec(open('catalog/tools.py').read())
```

but nothing happens and no traceback.

So how can I run a Python script inside of a Django project that creates objs in my DB?
I'm already aware of:
[How to execute a Python script from the Django shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/how-to-execute-a-python-script-from-the-django-shell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set). but no solution worked.

Comment: Are you running your script with python or with django? If you want to run a script in django context you should be creating a commnad.

Comment: the second answer of "How to execute a Python script from the Django shell? " is the best.it works,try it

Comment: I'm running the script with python, I'm new to Django and not aware of commands, I'll go search the docs

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to make a management command that can be run by typing

`python manage.py <insert_name_here>`

You can read more about it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/