# How to import Django models from script started with Popen() from views.py?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, subprocess, modulenotfounderror

I want to start a python script in a different process when a certain request arrives at my django server.
I can successfully start it, but its imports fail.

In my django app, I have a `views.py`.
In this I have a [`ViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) with an `update()` method that looks like this (reduced snippet to relevant code):

```
from . import models # notice this import, which works

def update(self, request, pk=None):
    dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'Process.py')
    p = subprocess.Popen(["python", filename],
                         stdout=sys.stdout, 
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This works as expected: When performing the appropriate request that causes `update()` to be called, it executes `Process.py`, which is a file in the same directory as `views.py`.

In `Process.py`, I want to access the models of the django backend, so I do as I did before:

```
from . import models

# more code here
```

But I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'models'
```

**Why does this import fail in `Process.py` even though it works for `views.py`?**

I tried

- a suggestion on the internet that the environment should be setup to be the same for the child process, like so:

  ```
  p = subprocess.Popen(["python", filename],
                       env = {'PYTHONPATH': os.pathsep.join(sys.path)}, # this is new
                       stdout=sys.stdout, 
                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  ```

  But that failed to start python at all:

  ```
  Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
  ```
- to write the import statement in `Process.py` in a different way:

  ```
  from models import stuff
  ```

  Oddly enough, this does import `models.py` (yay!) but fails deeper down the rabbit hole with:

  ```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<django project name>'
  ```

  Said rabbit hole starts at the first model class in `models.py` and then dives into django code, ending up at some bootstrapper:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path to django app>\Process.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models import stuff
  File "<path to django app>\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class <some model class>(models.Model):
  File "<path to conda environment>\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "<path to conda environment>\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "<path to conda environment>\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "<path to conda environment>\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "<path to conda environment>\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "<path to conda environment>\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "<path to conda environment>\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  ```

  It looks like django interferes with my imports somehow, but I'm not sure how and how to correct them.

**How do I successfully import (and use) `models.py` of a [django](/questions/tagged/django) app from a python script that's started with `subprocess.Popen(...)` from `views.py` of [django-rest-framework](/questions/tagged/django-rest-framework)?**

---

### from the comments

> Is Process.py a regular Python script, or is it written as a Django Management Command?

It's a regular script.
I modified it for debugging purposes like so:

```
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)

from . import models
```

> What happens if you run the script manually from the shell? Same error?

| from shell | django `views.py` via `Popen()` |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| windows cmd: `django-project>python manage.py shell` then `In [1]: from django-app import Process` | see above | call detail |
| success | `ImportError: cannot import name 'models'` | result |
| includes `django-project` path and empty path | includes `django-project/django-app` | differences of `sys.path` |

Comment: Is `Process.py` a regular Python script, or is it written as a [Django Management Command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)? What happens if you run the script manually from the shell? Same error?

Comment: @C14L just a regular python script (the `import` statement alone reproduces the error). Thank you for the suggestion. I am in the process of doing more research about django's commands, [based on this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16853755/11398730). I managed to create a custom command and execute it via `manage.py` with working imports, however: how would I go about executing that as a separate process?

Comment: I'm just guessing: leave the `PYTHONPATH` like in your example above and change the `["python", filename]` to `["python", "manage.py", filename]`.

Comment: @C14L You got me on the right track: With your suggestion I was able to invoke the Django-Management-Comment version of `Process.py` I mentioned earlier and solved my concern "_however: how would I go about executing that as a separate process?_" - simply by doing `while True:` in the handle method that never returns, which is fine, because the call is still wrapped in `Popen()`. Thanks. Feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked :) I added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.py` should be a [Django Management Command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/), so that the Django Framework is loaded and `model.py` used by Django.

The `PYTHONPATH` is still required so that Django knows where the base directory is.

Instad of `["python", filename]`, the process can be started with `["python", "manage.py", filename]`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the reference to your **Django app**, to **import all models** from it, you have to do in the python script:

```
from <django-app-name>.models import *
```

Comment: nope: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-app-name'`

Comment: And the question remains: why would it take a different import compared to the sibling module `views.py`?

Comment: If you process script is located on the same level that views.py and models.py, only "from . import models" should work fine. Can you share a print of your project folder structure?

Comment: I thought that as well. The thing is that Django needs a bit of initialisation/setup/bootstrapping  for the API etc. to be available. A regular script lives outside that environment. Nevermind, I solved the problem via django commands. Thank you for your answer.