# How to import Django models in a script started with Popen()

Tags: python, django

My question is very similar [with this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532330/how-to-import-django-models-from-script-started-with-popen-from-views-py). The difference in my case is that the python script I want to start as a subprocess (`listener1.py`), is part of my project, just on a different app.

This is my project structure:

```
my_project
    ├── my_app1 #This app contains models,views etc.
    │   ├── models.py
    │   └── apps.py
    │   └── ...
    ├── logic_app #This app contains several unrelated python scripts
    │   └── ManagerScript.py
    │   └── listener1.py
    │   └── ...
```

In my `apps.py`:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app1'
    def ready(self):
        #Once app is ready, start the following script as a thread
        thread = Thread(target=ManagerScript.main)
        thread.start()
```

In `ManagerScript.py`:

```
#This thread is responsible for starting listener1.py as a Subprocess
#(because this is a thread I can successfully import my Models here)
#from my_app1 import models #This would work!
        
tmp =  ['python3','path/to/listener1.py']
Popen(tmp, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```

In `listener1.py`:

```
from my_app1 import models #Does not work!
...
```

My question is, considering the fact that the subprocess `listener1.py` is in `logic_app` folder, how could I import my `Models` in `listener1.py` script without using  [Django Management Commands](https://www.google.com/search?q=Django%20Management%20Command&oq=Django%20Management%20Command&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.48j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? (Because using them would require to change my current project structure)

Answer (score 0):

You can run them through the Django shell. Without writing it as a command.

```
Python manage.py shell
exec(open(<path-to-file>).read()))
```

Comment: The `listener1.py` should automatically start once the `my_app1` is ready. Could I integrate your solution on `ManagerScript.py` ?