# import json not working with shell and manage.py Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-manage.py

I am writing some python scripts for my Django project. And I am running it using manage.py and shell.

`import json` is not working if I am running it with manage.py and sell.

But it is working if I try without shell and manage.py I don't know why this is happening.

**With manage.py and shell: (Not working)**

```
python3 manage.py shell < custom_scripts/imports.py
Error: NameError: name 'json' is not defined
```

**Without manage.py and shell: (Works)**

```
python3 custom_scripts/imports.py
```

**Code inside the script:**

```
    import json
    
    print(json.loads("{}"))
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be the recommended way to do such a thing from the `shell`, if this is something that will be run multiple times you can create custom commands to run this for you.

Please see the [answer by @danodonovan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16853755/9304280) for a similar issue.

Comment: It just a one-time script that I need to run.