# SMTp Django email reminder for expired drugs

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework, smtp

I would like to have a function on my app where people are notified when the expiry date of a drug is approaching. Like 2 months before it expires. I am currently using smtp for my emails but I would need help writing a view for this and signals.py

Comment: You could set up a cron job to run a python script which will query the database and send the relevant emails, if needed. The [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40402223/2996101) is done with: `echo 'import myscript' | python manage.py shell`